# how can I upload an image & store it in a local folder in springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I created new folder, "poster", under /src/main/resources, & so I want to store any images I upload to a form to be stored in /src/main/resources. Is there a simple way to do it?
I dont really understand the methods online.. Appreciate any help!

This is the class that handles renaming the file and saving it.. I got this error
-> Error: class path resource [src/main/resources/poster] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

This is my MovieService class

```
@Service
public class MovieService {
    
    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepo; 
    @Autowired 
    ServletContext ctx;


    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    public String addMovie(Movie movie, MultipartFile photo) throws IOException {
        String filename = "";

        try {
            // Get the resource URL
            Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:src/main/resources/poster");
            URL resourceUrl = resource.getURL();

            // Convert URL to file path
            String basePath = resourceUrl.getPath();
            String filePath = basePath + "/" + filename;

            // Copy the file input stream to the destination
            Files.copy(photo.getInputStream(), Paths.get(filePath), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

            // Save the file into the repository
            movie.setPoster("/poster/" + filename);
            movieRepo.save(movie);

            System.out.println(filename);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.err.println(filename);
        }

        return "addMovie";
    }
    
}
```

addMovie.html

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Add Movies</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h3 class="text-center heading">Add New Movie</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <form action="#" th:action="@{/dashboard/movies/add-movie}" method="post" th:object="${movie}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group form-row">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Movie Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="m_title" placeholder="Movie Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-row">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Release Date</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="date" required class="form-control" name="reldate">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-row">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Duration</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <textarea name="duration" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-row">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Photo</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                       <input type="file" accept=".jpg,.png" required class="form-control-file" name="photo">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-row">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Description :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <textarea name="descr" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Add Movie">            
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```